# Java objacts makenew object that override current object

Tags: java, object

I have a class and I want something like this:

```
   public class MainClass{
     .
     .
     .
      public makenew(){
        this=new ClassName()

     }

   }
```

so when I call makenew the object changes.

Can I do this?

Comment: What is the relationship between ClassName and MainClass?

Comment: ClassName extends MainClass

Comment: class ClassName extends MainClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't change an existing object to be an instance of a different class.  You can stop using the old object and start using a *different* object instead, but you can't change the identity of an object after it's created.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot assign anything to `"this"`. `"this"` is a reference to the current object, but is not an L-value. This is not allowed in Java.